# Solutions of the complex equation $|z^2(z-\overline{z-4i})| = |z\overline{z} -z(z-4i)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Solve the following complex equation:
>   $|z^2(z-\overline{z-4i})| = |z\overline{z} -z(z-4i)|$

I tried to solve this equation in the following way:
$$|z^2(z-(\overline{z-4i}))| = |z\overline{z} -z(z-4i)| \rightarrow |z^2(z-(\overline{z-4i}))| - |z\overline{z} -z(z-4i)| \rightarrow |z^2(z-(\overline{z-4i})) - z\overline{z} -z(z-4i))| \rightarrow |z^2(z-\overline{z} +4i - z\overline{z} -z(z-4i))| \rightarrow |z^2(z-\overline{z} +4i - z\overline{z} -z(z-4i))|$$

And here I can't simplify the expression anymore.

Comment: Did you try splitting into real and imaginary parts?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing, parenthesis are missing and you seem to believe that $|z|-|w|=0\Leftrightarrow |z-w|=0$, which is false, take $z=1,w=i$.

Comment: @C.Falcon Sorry for the parenthesis. I've just added them. And thanks for the hint, I'll try to find another way to solve the problem.

Comment: @abiessu "Did you try splitting into real and imaginary parts?" Eeagh...

Comment: Hint: Note that $$|z^2(z-\overline{z-4i})| = |z|^2|z-\overline{z-4i}|$$ and that $$|z\overline{z} -z(z-4i)|=|z|\,|\overline{z} -(z-4i)|$$ and use the fact that, for every $w$, $$|w|=|\overline{w}|$$

Comment: @Did thanks for the hint. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write the equation as: $$|z|^2 \, |z - \overline{z-4i}| \,=\, |z| \,|\bar z - (z - 4i)|$$

Note that $z - \overline{z-4i} \,=\, \overline{\bar z - (z - 4i)}$ so the two have the same modulus.

Then break it down by cases:

- $z - \overline{z-4i} = 0$
- $|z|^2 = |z|$
- $\cdots$